# Pearson correlation vs. logistic regression coefficients

Tags: logistic

From a bunch of data points which look like:

```
1   1   1
1   1   1
1   1   1
1   0   1
1   0   1
1   0   0
1   0   1
1   0   0
1   0   1
1   0   0
0   1   0
0   1   0
0   1   0
0   1   0
0   1   0
0   1   1
0   0   1
0   0   1
0   0   1
0   0   1
```

I get correlation coefficients as:

```
1                   -0.301511345                    0.204124145
-0.301511345                    1                   -0.287213479
0.204124145                 -0.287213479                    1
```

and after paired logistic regression the non-constant coefficients look like the following:

```
xx                  -1.258                  0.8473
-1.258                  xx                  -1.204
0.8473                  -1.204                  xx
```

In above, by regressing column 1 on column 2 I get non-constant coeff as -1.258 and after regression column 1 on column 3, I get 0.8473 and so on.

How do I interpret the above numbers?

Edit: I have a system which sends signal to 3 locations every 10 seconds. It gathers information about whether they are active or not. I am trying to understand if there is any relation between those systems in terms of when they are alive.

I calculated correlation matrix using the corr function in matlab.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What question are you trying to answer?  What do you want to learn from your data?  You should figure out what your question is, then decide on what statistics to compute in order to answer that question.

Computing statistics that you know how to compute, then asking what they mean is kind of like going to a doctor and saying that you found a bottle of aspirin and want to know what symtoms you should develope so that taking the aspirin will cure you.